# How to avoid the background to appear in between two edge-to-edge-placed antialiased patterns described in SVG?

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, antialiasing

[image: Appearing background in between two patterns]
As shown in the above picture, the default (and logic) behavior of SVG rasterizers will let the background appear in between two edge-to-edge placed antialiased patterns. Is there a way to tell the rasterizer to somehow merge the patterns together so to avoid this artifact?

Let's be clear. I have no intention whatsoever to create a new rasterizer for this. I am just asking wether SVG implements such an option or not.

Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to solve this. The easiest is to specify "shape-rendering=crispEdges" which will remove anti-aliasing.